# Yammer Rest API sender_type = "guide"

Tags: api, rest, yammer

We have developed a site that uses the Yammer rest API to retrieve the latest Yammer posts.

We've had an issue where a user has posted a message but the sender_type field is "guide" and not "user". I have looked at the post and other posts that are similar and the other posts all have the sender_type = "user".

```
       "sender_id": 130784,
       "replied_to_id": null,
       "created_at": "2016/02/22 07:13:29 +0000",
       "network_id": 130886,
       "message_type": "update",
       "sender_type": "guide",
```

Snippet of the incoming JSON message. We have asked the user and he has not done anything different and their other posts have the send_type as "user". The only difference I can see is that the attachment has been deleted from the post. Other than that the post is a normal post.

If anyone could shed some light on this this would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual question/problem? Do you want to know why a post has this sender_type instead of user?

Comment: Hi Brian, my understanding is that if a user posts a message on Yammer that the sender_type will be 'user' and in most instances this is the case. But for some reason when this user posted a message the sender_type was "guide" and I'm trying to see if anyone knows what set of conditions need to occur for a message to have a sender_type of "guide"  if any.  We use the data from the Yammer rest api to determine who posted the message, when the send_type is "guide' the sender_id is different from the user who actually posted the message.  The sender_id according to the docs is a virtual user.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/mammerla/YammerIntegration/blob/master/Yammer/SenderType.cs
the following types of `sender_type` are used at Yammer.

- `user`: Indicates that the creator of a message is a standard user.
- `guide`: Indicates that the message was created to help a user and community within Yammer, e.g., "Welcome to the network, John Doe"
- `bot`: Programmatically created messages, such as those created by an RSS or Twitter import.
- `chat`: Messages created via the chart feature.
- `announcement`: Indicates that the message was created to server as an announcement.
- `system`: System message created on behalf of a user, e.g., "John Doe created a group Foo".